# Mongo - Database getting offline after many requests

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, scrapy

I using MongoDB to store data scraped from web using Scrapy as **scraper** . The problem is, when I start to run a long process of scraping using multiple spiders the Mongo crashes and the spiders start to receive the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/search/decapod/updater/updater/pipelines.py", line 90, in process_item
    self.db[self.collection_name].insert_one(dict(item))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 693, in insert_one
    session=session),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 607, in _insert
    bypass_doc_val, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 595, in _insert_one
    acknowledged, _insert_command, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1242, in _retryable_write
    with self._tmp_session(session) as s:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1571, in _tmp_session
    s = self._ensure_session(session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1558, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1511, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1544, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 427, in get_server_session
    None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 199, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongodb.getmore.com.br:27017: timed out
```

How can I automatically restart Mongo when it crashes or prevent this to happening?

I'm currently running mongo on a EC2 instance `t2.small`.

Comment: When you say long process do you mean that it keeps the connection open for a long time? What version of MongoDb are you using?

Comment: @Akrion, exactly. I'm currently using version 3.2.20

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that your are not having `keepAlive` in your settings for the connection.

Can you try setting your `keepAlive: 1` in your connection options:

```
options: {
  server: {
    socketOptions: {
      keepAlive: 1,
      connectTimeoutMS: 30000
    }
  }
}
```

Here is more on the [optional parameters](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/reference/connecting/connection-settings/)

Comment: where I should create this config?

Comment: It is part of the Optional parameters: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/reference/connecting/connection-settings/. It is on by default in later MongodB versions.

Comment: I think that is not the problem, because what is happening is that the mongo is getting offline and not the client of pymongo

Comment: OK if you think so. Ware you able to try it however if it did not make any difference?

Comment: I'm trying to find a method to execute this command through `pymongo`

Comment: No this should be a optional parameter to your app when connecting to mongoDB.

Comment: That is exactly what I trying to do.

Comment: Find it: 
`socketKeepAlive: (boolean) DEPRECATED Whether to send periodic keep-alive packets on connected sockets. Defaults to True. Disabling it is not recommended, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#does-tcp-keepalive-time-affect-mongodb-deployments”`

From: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html